# Regular expression, not finding match

Tags: c++, regex, fstream

I have code that goes through a file to find dates but its not returning that it found a match to my regular expression.

CODE:

```
std::string s(line);
std::smatch m;
std::regex e("^[0,1]?\d{1}\/(([0-2]?\d{1})|([3][0,1]{1}))\/(([1]{1}[9]{1}[9]{1}\d{1})|([2-9]{1}\d{3}))$");   
std::cout << "Target sequence: " << s << std::endl;
std::cout << "Regular expression: ^[0,1]?\d{1}\/(([0-2]?\d{1})|([3][0,1]{1}))\/(([1]{1}[9]{1}[9]{1}\d{1})|([2-9]{1}\d{3}))$" << std::endl;
std::cout << "The following matches and submatches were found:" << std::endl;

while (std::regex_search(s, m, e)) {
    for (auto x : m) std::cout << x << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    s = m.suffix().str();
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Success
Target sequence: 12/28/2002     2   15   38   43   50
Regular expression: ^[0,1]?d{1}/(([0-2]?d{1})|([3][0,1]{1}))/(([1]{1}[9]{1}[9]{1
}d{1})|([2-9]{1}d{3}))$
The following matches and submatches were found:
Enter q to quit:
```

Is my regular expression not correct or is it something else?

Comment: This doesn't fix stuff, but just a simplification of your regex: `^[0,1]?\d\/(([0-2]?\d)|(3[0,1]))\/((199\d)|([2-9]\d{3}))$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause is in your regex and in how you specify the string literal:

- Before we make any fix to your regex, try printing out the string literal to the console:

  ```
  std::cout << "^[0,1]?\d{1}\/(([0-2]?\d{1})|([3][0,1]{1}))\/(([1]{1}[9]{1}[9]{1}\d{1})|([2-9]{1}\d{3}))$";
  ```

  You will see that `\` are missing, and `<regex>` can't see them.

  To specify `\` in a string, you need to escape it, `\\`.

  By the way, printing the string is one of the debugging step in languages where there is no dedicated RegExp literal and the construction must be done via string.
- You are anchoring your search with `^` and `$`. It will only find a match if the date is on its own in a line, and there must not even be leading or trailing spaces.
- You are having a lot of redundant syntax, e.g. `[1]{1}` or . A character class with single character (which is not a special character in regex) can be taken out, i.e. `1{1}`. And `{1}` is **always** redundant, i.e. `[1]{1}` can be shortened to `1`.
- `/` doesn't need escaping, either in the string literal or regex.
- Fixing the syntactic problems above and remove `^` and `$`:

  ```
  "[0,1]?\\d/(([0-2]?\\d)|(3[0,1]))/((199\\d)|([2-9]\\d{3}))"
  ```
- By `[0,1]`, you probably want `[01]`. When you want to match either character `A` or `B`, just place them next to each other in character class `[AB]`. Your `[0,1]` will also match a comma `,`.
- You can drop the `()` in `([0-2]?\\d)`, `(3[0,1])`. The same for year portion. The outer capturing group is enough.
- Applying the 2 points above:

  ```
  "[01]?\\d/([0-2]?\\d|3[01])/(199\\d|[2-9]\\d{3})"
  ```

The regex should now work when you want to extract data, but not so nice if you want to use it to validate. I don't know why you restrict the year to 1990 to 9999, but it's probably your business logic.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough explanation. I do not know how to write regular expressions, this is my first time using one and I literally know nothing about them. I just copied this expression from google. Do you know of any resources where I can learn about them. Also, I do not want it to be restricted to 1990 to 9999, how would I fix that? Again thank you.

Comment: @DaveCribbs: What range do you want for the year? As for resources, in case of C++, check the ECMA/JavaScript RegExp (since regex in C++ is based on it) **first**, then check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075 if you need deeper explanation.

Comment: Is there a way to make it accept any year or does it have to have a specification?

Comment: @DaveCribbs: Depends on your application. You can make it `\d+` if you don't really care about the number of digits of the year.